# Debugging edits to .NET core app in Visual Studio don't take effect

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

When I'm debugging a .NET core app in Visual Studio, I can pause it and make valid changes before resuming execution of the process. However, the process runs with the previous code and, when a breakpoint is hit, the highlighted text seems to only match the number of characters that were previously on that line.

Example:

`Thread.Sleep(2000)` becomes  `Thread.Sleep(123456)`, and the breakpoint will highlight the line up to the 4.

This only happens for .NET Core apps. Is this a bug, "feature", or a setting I can change?

Comment: Probably a bug, since .NET Core tooling in VS2015 was only preview and not production-supported. For .NET Core and ASP.NET Core it's recommended to use VS2017

Comment: Did you check [IntelliTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264944.aspx) as mentioned in [How to: Enable and Disable Edit and Continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx)?

Comment: I tried that setting, but nothing seemed to change. 
@CamiloTerevinto is most likely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This only happens for .NET Core apps. Is this a bug, "feature", or a setting I can change?

What CamiloTerevinto said is right. This is a known [Issue #7902](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/7902) on GitHub that **Edit and Continue does not work for .Net Core at this point in Visual Studio 2015**.

For more information about VS2015 ENC changes, have a look at this blog entry: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/04/29/net-enc-support-for-lambdas-and-other-improvements-in-visual-studio-2015/

Besides, this issue was resolved at the Visual Studio 2017 RTM. You can check it on Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I now have this issue with a .NET Core 2.0 app (simple console app with one class) I have created in the latest version VS 2017 Enterprise edition.